# Oracle database startup fails several times. Giving ksvcreate

Tags: oracle, startup, shutdown

Last night my production server database (ORACLE 10.2.04) was showing me number of connection exceeded as some times it show me. Then as usual I shut down abort my database then at the time database start-up it just stays blank and writing no error log and alert log after 30 min I abort the shut down by `CTRL+c` and issue the start up process once again then in `alert.log` file I found the `ksvcreate: Process() creation failed` this error but my database failed to start up please help me out why it is happening and any solution for it or nay parameter check for it.

Comment: Please check first permission on the OS file system, either oracle is able to read and write files to that file system (where database files resides). I was also facing the same problem once.

Comment: You might need to clear up semaphores and shared memory segments if there's still some remnants of an Oracle instance there. Edit your question with the output of `ipcs -a|grep oracle`

Comment: "*then as usual I shut down abort my database*" - that is a terrible way to do "usually". `shutdown abort` should be the last resort. `shutdown immediate` should be the "usual" way of shutting down Oracle.

Comment: This error usually indicates that the server has run out of memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Did anything on that server change recently?
- What OS/version?
- What hardware sizing?
- What processes are on it?
- How much memory is allocated for the database[s]? (sum sga & pga)

Normally this error has to do with a lack of resources. What else is running on this server that consumes memory? There is a good chance that due to lack of memory your server is swapping and doing so, it takes too long to start processes.

Monitor your memory usage.

If your application does bulk updates, without limits, this could easily fill your entire memory. See [Bulk Processing with BULK COLLECT and FORALL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html) for a good explanation. If your data set is growing over time, surprises are waiting to happen. Use limits in the pl/sql code.

Shutting down a database because there are performance problems is not exactly a solution for a problem, it is the denial of a real existing problem. Normally a database is online and available, a solid piece of foundation for an application. If your database/data has any value for your company, hire a dba to help you evaluate your systems.

Comment: No change have done recently. OS VERSION RHEL5.8 64bit. hardware Size 64Gb ram 32Gb of SWAP. 2 Processor xeon 2.4 GHz having 12 core each .SGA AND PGA  16Gb. Only Our Database is running on this server.

Comment: don't forget that the pga_aggregate_target does not inpose a limit. Your app can easily allocate more than available memory, causing swap problems. Setup memory usage monitoring.

Comment: Could u please explain it little elaborately

Comment: your application could be using bulk updates on large collections. See <http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html> for a nice example and explanation.